# While I was working on solidity project I got the following error

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, solidity-0.6.x

`npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost` is not working.
It says

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')

My deploy script

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const ChatApp = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ChatApp");
  const chatApp = await ChatApp.deploy();
  await chatApp.deployed();
  console.log(`Contract Address: ${ChatApp.address}`);
}

main()
  .catch((error) => { 
    console error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144451/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-jsonrpcprovider)

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading "ethers" to version 5.4 in your package.json, then delete your node_modules folder and finally run "npm install" again.