# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, json-rpc, rpc

```
const ethers = require("ethers");

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MYKEYISHERE')

web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log)
```

Error:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MYKEYISHERE`)
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look at this post.

[EthersJS Listening to events with NodeJS Strange Errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144381/ethersjs-listening-to-events-with-nodejs-strange-errors)

Had the same problem few days ago, turned out to be problem with a beta release of ethers.js.

The fix for me was to downgrade `"ethers"` to version `5.4` in the `config.json`, then remove node_modules folder and lastly `npm install` to install ethers again.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 14):

The newer version of Ethers seems to be unstable ethers 6.0.2...
To solve this error downgrade your ethers version to 5.7.2 by going to your package.json

"ethers": "5.7.2"

now on your cli use npm install ethers@5.7.2 or yarn add ethers@5.7.2 depending on your package manager and that should solve your error.

Comment: Worked like a charm thank you

Answer (score 9):

I am using ethers version **6.2.3**, You can directly import it from ethers package.

```js
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require('ethers');
```

For more info refer to this link
https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/3924.

Entire code I am using to deploy contract locally using **ethers** on Ganache

```js
//importing thers and JsonRpcProvider
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require('ethers');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
async function main() {
  // Json Rpc Provider - Connecting to local blockchain
  const provider = new JsonRpcProvider('address'); // add your rpc server url from Ganache

  // Connect to wallet to sign transactions
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    'Add your private key here',
    provider
  );

  //Read ABI which you get post compilation using solc
  const abi = fs.readFileSync('./fileName.abi', 'utf8');
  
  //Read Binary which you get post compilation using solc
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    './fileName.bin',
    'utf8'
  );

  //Create Contract factory object to deploy
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log('Deploying, Please wait...');
  
  // Deploy and you are good to go
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  console.log(contract);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Response

```bash
Deploying, Please wait...
BaseContract {
  target: '0x35aD58985b61f634A8108A7ffcF6D438ab701ffB',
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [ [FunctionFragment], [FunctionFragment], [FunctionFragment] ],
    deploy: ConstructorFragment {
      type: 'constructor',
      inputs: [],
      payable: false,
      gas: null
    },
    fallback: null,
    receive: false
  },
  runner: Wallet {
    provider: JsonRpcProvider {},
    address: '0x8EDA89abFAB838dc350c12fA8b6D9Ad630380B2f'
  },
  filters: {},
  fallback: null,
  [Symbol(_ethersInternal_contract)]: {}
}
```

Comment: One more thing to mention ethers version 6 is in Beta so you can downgrade to version 5 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem few days ago, turned out to be problem with a beta release of ethers.js.

The fix for me was to downgrade "ethers" to **version 5.4** in the **package.json**, then remove node_modules folder and lastly **npm install** to install ethers again.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pYn9.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue, when I changed the version it worked adequately.
change the version (6.0.3 to 5.7.2). The latest version is not stable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the problem is in the version of the ethers, so I changed the version of ethers to ^5.7.2 in package.json
Then I deleted the whole folder node_modules and again installed all components

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in the latest ether.js version. **Change the ether version to 5.4.0** in the package.json file then **delete node modules** and reinstall it using **npm install.**

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the `hardhat-ethers` [plugin docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers) you must install `'ethers@^5.0.0'` version and it resolves the issue.

Comment: thank you for mentioning the source of information. I was wondering why version 6.2.3 is not working.

Answer (score 1):

`npm install ethers@5.7.2`

```
const provider = new thers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545" );
```

option 2. Have latest version and in use

```
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require("ethers");
const provider = new JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545")
```

Answer (score 1):

- With `ethers@v5`

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
```

- With `ethers@v6`

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to import JsonRpc provider at the beginning.

```
const { JsonRpcProvider } = require("ethers");
```

Comment: This didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

For this error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonRpcProvider')

run this command to solve this issue;

```
npm install --save-dev ethers@^5
```

or

```
yarn add --dev ethers@^5
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue yesterday, what I did was to uninstall ethers and reinstall a lower version, particularly from 6.8 to 5.4.

Answer (score -1):

> simple:

npm uninstall ethers

npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers 'ethers@^5.0.0'

> In hardhat.config.js

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");